# Preview pop-up window using JQuery

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am doing an application like a Form builder.

I am having a design page where I am generating the Fields using JQuery and displaying them each in a Div in the Preview panel of the same page.

In my code I am saving all the Fields in the Form by iterating through all the Divs in the Preview panel.

Now I want to add a functionality to show all the Divs in the preview panel in a pop - up window like when I click the Save Form button it must show all those DIvs in the Preview panel in the Window like a Preview and then it has to save the Form .

How to include the Preview option in the Code also to show the preview in a pop-up window?

My code to save the Form is like:

```
    $("#fb_contentarea_col1down21 div").each(function() { 
                    var checked="false";     
                        var id=$(this).attr("id");

                        //var fname=$("#label"+id+"").text();

                        var fsize=$("#input"+id+"").width();

                        var ftype=$("#input"+id+"").attr('data-attr');

                        var finstr=$("#instr"+id+"").text();

                        var fname=$("#label"+id+"").clone().html().replace(/<span.*/,'');

                        if($("#label"+id+"> span.req").length > 0)
                        {

                         checked="true";

                        }

                        $.ajax({
                                       type: "POST",
                                      url: "http://localhost/FormBuilder/index.php/forms/saveField",
```

data: "sequence_no="+id+"&name="+fname+"&type="+ftype+"&size="+fsize+"&instr="+finstr+"&formid="+getformid+"&required="+checked,

```
                                       success: function(msg){
                                    //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg);
                                        }//success
                                       });//ajax




            });//Loop
```

My fb_contentarea_col1down21 has all the Divs showing all the Fields of my Form.

```
I am iterating through it and saving all the Fields.
```

How to make all these to show like a preview in a pop-up window using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise PHP and send the values you retrieve from the form (using JavaScript) using the GET method.

Now you wouldn't actually be posting anything, just opening a new pop-up window using JavaScript with your desired URL with all the parameters appended to the end of the URL:

```
http://mysite.com/somepage.php?param1=hello&param2=world
```

Have the PHP page that you open in the new pop-up windows retrieve these values:

```
$param1 = $_GET["param1"];
$param2 = $_GET["param2"];
```

And then utilise these variables to create a preview panel.

NOTE:

> The spec for URL length does not
>   dictate a minimum or maximum URL
>   length, but implementation varies by
>   browser. On Windows: Opera supports
>   ~4050 characters, IE 4.0+ supports
>   exactly 2083 characters, Netscape 3 ->
>   4.78 support up to 8192 characters before causing errors on shut-down,
>   and Netscape 6 supports ~2000 before
>   causing errors on start-up. ~ (via [What is the limit on QueryString / GET / URL parameters?](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/forms/what-is-the-limit-on-querystring/get/url-parameters.html))

Thanks